# AngularJS $filter date not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

Im trying to set the format of a date as 'dd/MM/yyyy' using angular's $filter in this way:

```
var toDate;
$scope.endDate = {
        value: new Date(2013, 9, 22)
};

$scope.$watch('metric.value', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        toDate = $filter('date')($scope.endDate,'dd/MM/yyyy');
        console.log(toDate);
}
```

And the output of the console shows the following:

```
Object {value: Tue Oct 22 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)}
```

How can I actually change it to the format dd/MM/yyyy and parse it to a String?

Comment: toDate = $filter('date')($scope.endDate.value, 'dd/MM/yyyy');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you error when typing.

Maybe you need filter correct code below:

`toDate = $filter('date')($scope.endDate.value,'dd/MM/yyyy');`

Comment: Totally correct. Second time that I have the same mistake... Thanks!